# Android's Vertical Linear Layout weighting doesn't take into account actionbar height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

For my Spanish WotD app I have 3 cardviews sitting in a linear layout. The top and bottom ones are equally weighted and the middle one is more important so it is weighted accordingly. No matter what, the bottom one seems to hang over the screen (about the size of the actionbar), even after changing around the weights.

It appears that when Android is calculating percentages, it doesn't account for the ActionBar at all. I've done what other people has said including changing to `match_parent`, 0dp for height, but nothing is working. I have no idea why.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cinnamint.cotidiano.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_header"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_of_week_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/word"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/definition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_date"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Look at the screenshot (sorry if it is hard to see), the bottom card clearly hangs over

Edit: Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cinnamint.cotidiano">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Styles:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Edit: activity_main.xml

```
ding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.cinnamint.cotidiano.MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.cinnamint.cotidiano;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private static List<Words> availableWords;

    private long MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    private long daysSinceCinnamintEpoch;

    private Calendar cinnamintEpoch;

    private static final int CINNAMINT_EPOCH_DAY = 15;
    private static final int CINNAMINT_EPOCH_MONTH = 7 - 1;
    private static final int CINNAMINT_EPOCH_YEAR = 2016;

    private static final String TAG = "CINNAMINT_COTIDIANO";


    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // July 14, 2016: day 1 of development
        // Add the appropriate number of days
        cinnamintEpoch = Calendar.getInstance();
        cinnamintEpoch.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, CINNAMINT_EPOCH_DAY);
        cinnamintEpoch.set(Calendar.MONTH, CINNAMINT_EPOCH_MONTH);
        cinnamintEpoch.set(Calendar.YEAR, CINNAMINT_EPOCH_YEAR);


        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        daysSinceCinnamintEpoch = (long) Math.ceil(
                                            (today.getTimeInMillis() - cinnamintEpoch.getTimeInMillis()) / MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY
                                            );

        Log.d(TAG, Long.toString(daysSinceCinnamintEpoch));


        WordDatabase wdb = new WordDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        wdb.open();
        availableWords = wdb.getEveryWordByDate(daysSinceCinnamintEpoch);
        wdb.close();

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), availableWords.size());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // Move to farthest right position
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(availableWords.size() - 1);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);


            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView dayOfWeekLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.day_of_week_label);
            TextView wordLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.word);
            TextView definitionLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.definition);
            TextView dateLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date);

            int sectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);


            // July 14, 2016: day 1 of development
            // Add the appropriate number of days
            Calendar fragmentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            fragmentDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, CINNAMINT_EPOCH_DAY + (sectionNumber - 1));
            fragmentDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, CINNAMINT_EPOCH_MONTH);
            fragmentDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, CINNAMINT_EPOCH_YEAR);

            // Format the day and date
            Date date = fragmentDate.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM, yyyy", new Locale("es", "ES"));

            Words targetWord = MainActivity.availableWords.get(sectionNumber - 1);
            String dayOfWeekContent = (new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", new Locale("es", "ES"))).format(date.getTime());
            String wordContent = targetWord.getText();
            String definitionContent = targetWord.getDefinition();
            String dateContent = format.format(date);



            dayOfWeekLabel.setText(dayOfWeekContent);
            wordLabel.setText(wordContent);
            definitionLabel.setText(definitionContent);
            dateLabel.setText(dateContent);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private int items = 1;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int item_count) {
            super(fm);
            items = item_count;
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give android:weightSum="3" to your Linearlayout.

Comment: @Drv Thank you, unfortunately I forgot to mention I have tried that as per others suggestion and it seems to have not changed anything. I tried giving `android:weightSum="3"` in the LinearLayout and keeping `android:layout_weight="1"` for each of the 3 cardviews.

Comment: Where is the code that contains the ActionBar? Will you add this to the main post?

Comment: please describe properly and included relevant code

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 Thanks for your patience! I was considering moving to relative layout because it's easy but I'm kind of upset that I can't get this to work so I'll hold off on switching over for a while. Hopefully we can help find a solution?

Comment: @AmitVaghela Done, added manifest and styles

Comment: I actually just fixed this in someone else's project yesterday. I'm going to create an answer real fast once I find the code to copy.

Comment: If what I suggested did not work, let me know. In that case, I will need to see the code that contains the ActionBar (which is probably where you should put the layout behavior line anyway).

Comment: Can you add Java code for main activity

Comment: @OmarHossam Sure. Sorry it's so long, I didn't see anything in particular that would have been super useful. Also, the full code is on github https://github.com/Graystripe17/cadadia

Answer (score 0):

I have found the fix for multiple applications that don't take into account the actionbar size is adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the layout. In your case, I would put this in the LinearLayout. Also, you may have to put `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the LinearLayout.

**Fragments**
For others having this issue using Fragments, put this line in the layout (probably a FrameLayout) that contains the Fragment's `<include/>` statement.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know why but it doesn't work for me. I'll post activity_main.xml and keep trying.

Comment: Unless I'm blind, I can't see where you include the LinearLayout's file in your activity_main.xml. Where is it included?

Comment: I implemented a view pager that inflates each fragment through an adapter (fragment pager adapter). Thanks for your assistance so far, when I get home I will read more about appbarscrollviewbehavior.

Comment: Update: I still have this issue even when moving to relative layout! When I have layout_alignParentBottom="true" it still goes offscreen.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with Coordinate layout. When I rid ViewPager of your two lines, suddenly the end lines up perfectly but gets covered by the actionbar.

Comment: What I ended up doing was super frustrating. I was using AndroidStudio's prebuilt viewpager activity and that came with Coordinate Layout with Toolbar. The toolbar in general was invisible because of no scrolling so I scrapped it all. Now it works perfectly. I guess I still need to learn about the new AppBarLayout->Toolbar material design setup. Thanks to everyone for their assistance, I truly appreciate it. Full solution on https://github.com/Graystripe17/cadadia you can see where I commented out the toolbar in activity_main and styles